# Which core-js module transpiles es2015 object literals?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, core-js

I am about to migrate my vue frontend to core-js.

In my entry file I am loading these modules:

```
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/reflect';
```

I would have expected that 'core-js/es/object' might be the module which transpiles object literals i.e.

```
var test = 'some stuff';
var obj = {test};
```

to

```
var test = 'some stuff';
var obj = {test: test};
```

But that's not happening. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Core-js does not transpire code, it only acts as polyfill for the js base library. If you want to have things transpiled you will need to use Babel or something simular

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Babel is of course installed. I believe, I then have a misconception of the relationship between babel and core-js.

So I still need to set the respective transpilation directives in my .babelrc?

Comment: Yes. But is probably easier if you just use `@babel/present-env` since you don't need to configure stuff manually then. Also if you use preset-env Babel will automatically detect what polyfills you need and inject them, which means you don't have to import them manually

Comment: I think you've answered my question. If you post your comments as an "answer" I'll give you the respective points.